# Load MySQL Employees Sample Database into a already running docker container on Windows

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a MySQL Docker container running in my local Windows machine. I want to load Employees database into that docker container.

Employees Database Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/

I tried using MySQL Workbench and "Run SQL Script", but it's throwing below error:

```
[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 

'C:\\Users\\roul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp4fbw2bb4.cnf'
```

After reading some article I think we may have one option of attaching the script file location volume into the container and run the script from docker command prompt, but that I'm unable to do it.

Anyone here have already done that?

Answer (score 0):

Find the datadir of you MySQL Server:

`SHOW VARIABLES WHERE variable_Name LIKE "datadir"`

Copy the content of the folder to your datadir (\. copy the content of the folder, not the folder; maybe you want improve this to not mess the datadir):

`docker cp test_db-master/. CONTAINER:/var/lib/mysql/`

Run the script inside the container:

`docker exec -i CONTAINER /bin/bash -c "cd /var/lib/mysql/ && /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=123456 < /var/lib/mysql/employees.sql"`